# How does NSArray implements NSCopying protocol

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsarray

I guess it performs a shallow copy. But, if that is the case, how does it affect the objects in the array memory-wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it doesn't. It increases their retaincount and that's it.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `[array copy]` you can use `[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array copyItems:YES]` to make a new array with every items copied from the source.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this method as well. I just want to know what does the [array copy] method do exactly